# Importing multiple excel sheets from a onedrive folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to import multiple (30) Excel files from a onedrive folder, as far as it is the same data but from different days of the month I need to create a single DataFrame with it. The sheets I need to import have a specific format for which I need to use the 6 indexes into the column names and then from 80% of the columns, which I managed to do, the problem I face is whenever I try to read and create the DF that I plan to use. Here's what I've tried:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4] == "xlsx"]
df = []


for f in files_xlsx:
   data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name = 'MPS DEL DIA')
   df = df.append(data)
```

Whenever I run the code I get the following:

```
c:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:329: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
c:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:329: UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 3
      1 for f in files_xlsx:
      2     data = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name= 'MPS DEL DIA')
----> 3     df = df.append(data)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0):

`y.append(x)` method appends `x` to `y` and returns `None`. Therefore, you don't need to reassign `None` to the original collection.

Answer (score 0):

Smaller example:

```
df = []

for f in [1, 2, 3]:
    print(f"f: {f}")
    data = f
    df = df.append(data)

f: 1
f: 2
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Before the loop, you set `df` to be an empty list. In the loop, you append the value `f` into that list, but then assign the return value of the `append` function to df - which is `None`.

On the next loop, `df` is now `None`, so you're effectively trying to `None.append(2)` - which fails with the given error.

This would be how to implement it imho:

```
df = []

for f in [1, 2, 3]:
    print(f"f: {f}")
    data = f
    df.append(data)

print(df)
```